# Spring RSocket Kubernetes server - Side car to convert http requests from client?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud, rsocket

Small question regarding how to convert http requests into RSocket please.

The server setup is a very straightforward RSocket server.
The server is dockerized and deployed in Kubernetes.

Now there are many clients, I do not have control over them. The clients would like to talk to this RSocket server. The JSON payload the clients sends are all compatible with the RSocket server. However, all clients are just using http clients, not RSocket.

May I ask what is the easiest solution to convert the https requests send from the clients please?

What I tried: Built a layer in between, using Spring Cloud Gateway to take as input a http request, and forward it using a RSocket client.

The drawback of this solution is that there is now another app in the picture. Instead of maintaining one business RSocket application, there is a need to implement and maintain another web server entirely.

May I ask if there is some kind of sidecar pattern using maybe ngnix, istio, Kubernetes services, that can perform the same, without having to full blown develop another web app please?

May I ask what is the easiest solution to convert the https requests send from the clients please?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to convert the HTTP requests to rsocket?

Comment: The clients are all sending http requests only. Are you saying the client, all sending http requests only, can still reach the RSocket server ?(Because so far, I tried, and unfortunately, it is not working (client http -> server RSocket)

Comment: No I don't - I wonder, if exposing a simple HTTP endpoint for the clients would be sufficient, since I don't see any benefit from converting it. (Additional complexity, latency, less robust, ...)

Answer (score 1):

> May I ask if there is some kind of sidecar pattern using maybe ngnix, istio, Kubernetes services, that can perform the same, without having to full blown develop another web app please?

No, The concept maybe called broker gateway but not sidecar pattern. You should implements a broker gateway to conevert the protocol, such as HTTP(Rest), GraphQL, gRPC. You can refer a sample project [alibaba-rsocket-broker](https://github.com/alibaba/alibaba-rsocket-broker).